# What is the minimum share price for TSX Venture Exchange listings?

Tags: canada, stock-exchanges, toronto-stock-exchange

The Toronto Stock Exchange (TSX) does not have a specific minimum share price requirement. What about the TSX Venture Exchange? Does it have a minimum share price requirement for its listings?

Note that I'm not asking about the minimum initial offering price. I am asking about the minimum acceptable price to prevent delisting.

Comment: It would help if you showed what research you've tried, and what you've found (and what you can't find!). For instance, a couple of clicks in a search-engine led to the [TSX Venture Exchange Rulebook](https://www.tsx.com/resource/en/1465) (PDF). Its **Rule B.1.00 - Power to List and Delist** (page 13 of the document; 20 in the PDF) doesn't appear to explicitly mention a minimum price (it's mostly "at its discretion"), but that doesn't prove there isn't a minimum.